# How to make one word render under another

Tags: spacing, line-spacing, linguistics

I have text of word pairs and I want them to render by pair, one under another, like shown on the figure below:

[image]

**[UPDATE]** In the source words arrive in pairs: word1 + word2, word3 + word4, so I need them feed to latex in the sequence I receive (and have flow from left to right until line ends and then continue on the next line), therefore I *cannot* construct one line with word1 , word3, word5 and next line with word2, word4 and word6, it would require calculation of words length to check how many will fit a single line.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  This sounds like a linguistic construction,  You might look at the `expex` package.

Comment: Perfect!!! Could you make your comment an answer and I will accept it?

Comment: Should this occur inline (i.e., with other text around it)? Or is it a singular case of 3 words with some sub-scripted word.

Comment: There are  three main packages for doing this sort of thing. See [Numbered examples in linguistics that I can refer back to](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/77937) for details (although the question isn't exactly a duplicate, the answer covers the issue with examples for all three.

Comment: Do you literally mean `Word1 + Word2, `, with the inclusion of the `+` and `,` in the input stream?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I know everything can be solved with `stackengine` :) but I think the requirements in linguistics have been solved with specific packages designed for that.

Comment: @AlanMunn LOL.  Very well.  I shall sit this one out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a linguistic construction

You might look at the `expex` package.

That ordinarily sets the "linked" words in the same size type, so that might need some adjustment.

**Update:**
Alan Munn (who knows what he's talking about) recommends `gb4e` as an alternative to `expex`.

Comment: Upvote for mentioning about `linguistic`...

Comment: ExPex is a very good package, but it has its idiosyncrasies, since it's not particularly LaTeX-like and there are a couple of other good options, especially `gb4e`.

Comment: Thanks, @AlanMunn.  That's worth a separate answer that I'll vote for.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use the *tabbing* environment.
MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabbing}
        \= {\Huge Word 1} \= {\Large Word 3} \= {\LARGE Word 5}\\
        \> Word 2 \> Word 4 \> Word 6
    \end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

This generates

[image]

As you can see the font size can be modified wherever you want, *tabbing* will do the job and align any `\>` symbol with the corresponding `\=` symbol (reference). You must use the double antislash to start a new line.
You can also add extra space, make it bold, as you like.

Enjoy!

Comment: Sorry, I might was not clear enough, in the source words go in pairs: word1 + word2, word3 + word4, .. so I need them feed to latex in the sequence I receive, while your answer proposes me to split them what in upper line and what in lower line. But I never know how many words in the upper line, I just want the pairs to flow as they arrive.

Comment: OK, it's clearer. I would process that with some programming, probably with Python to create the LaTeX file, then compile to generate the PDF. But this is because I'm familiar with Python and probably don't really know the process you are dealing with. Good luck :)

Comment: @BaratSahdzijeu -- The information about how the words "arrive" in the input is important, and moreover would not change the nature of the question.  Adding that into the statement of the question would mean the question has more value for someone looking at it later.  Please do it.

Comment: There are special packages for doing this automatically, including line wrapping, and formatting of the different lines so tabbing is not really a good solution.